Which ensemble to use for annealing?
I am trying to do a simulation for solid Mg dopes GaN in LAMMPS where I follow the following procedure:

Energy minimization at 0K
Heating to 873K
Holding at 873K
Quenching to 300K

For this I am planning to do a npt ensemble heating upto the required temperature, followed by a nvt ensemple for holding it at 873K and finally an nvt enselble for quenching. I am new to LAMMPS, so can someone guide me about the correct choice of ensemble for each of the above steps?
